# Java FX 2 Heap Space

Tags: java, javafx-2

There are several fxml files and controllers in my Java FX 2 application.

1. LayoutController is layout.fxml controller that contains static layout element BorderPane. This controller has some methods:

- `BorderPane.setHeader`(Some method through which load header.fxml file and return Node)
- `BorderPane.setCenter`(Some method through which load center.fxml file and return Node)
- `initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle)` in which setHeader method calls.

2. HeaderController is header.fxml controller that contains control element TabPane.
   HeaderController has onSelected EventHandler. On this action into BorderPane.center inserts center.fxml.
3. CenterController is center.fxml controller that on initialize inserts control element TableView and fills it with data.

My problem is in memory leak. I get heap space while repeatedly selected tabs.

Comment: "I get heap space while repeatedly selected tabs." Does this mean that as you move back and forth between tabs you eventually get a memory leak? Don't mean to be rude, just trying to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try making use of JVM option -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError ?
You can read more about on this [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/javasdk/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.java.doc.diagnostics.60/diag/appendixes/cmdline/commands_jvm.html)

You should try to focus if the UI objects are getting recreated on each click rather than getting reused ? 
Please read following links to have more idea on this :
1) [Memory Leaks in JavaFX](http://objectsource.com/blogs/2009/11/memory-leaks-in-javafx/)
2) [Node object not getting GCed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7809679/javafx-node-objects-are-not-garbage-collected)

Comment: The provided links to memory management are related to JavaFX 1.x and are confusing in the context of a JavaFX 2 application.

Answer (score 0):

Realized method, that cleans all data in previous created controller like this:

```
public void dispose() {

 table.getColumns().clear();

 table.getItems.clear();

 table = null;
}
```

Is this the correct approach?